# Create collection in firestore if not exists (flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How would I go about checking if a collection exists in firestore and then creating it if it doesn't exist? I know how to add a document to the collection if it is created, but how to create an empty collection in Flutter is what I am missing.

Comment: You cannot create an empty collection in Cloud Firestore.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing as an empty collection in Firestore.  You can't create a collection without also creating a document it.  When you add a document to a collection, it will immediately exist and be visible in the console.  When you delete the last document in a collection, it will cease to exist.  The only way to check if a document exists is to query it in such a way that it will give you a document.

This is true for all client platforms - there is nothing special here for Flutter.

Comment: One minor tweak: technically, collections don't even exist.  You can view any collection name by just updating your URL when viewing Firestore to show a new name, e.g., for 'a-sample-collection': `/firestore/data/~2Fa-sample-collection`.  It's a bit of a different paradigm, but may be familiar to those who've dealt with other keyed object stores such as AWS S3 (where a folder also doesn't really exist).  You can think of collections as just a key prefixes for objects, and Firestore's organization scheme allows you to list objects by their common prefixes.